# How can I do actions when multiple divs are clicked ? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'll try to explain : I have a lot of divs that I am using as buttons (they're switching to red when you click on it).
It's a ranking system (for a videogame). Each rank has three step (1-2-3).
The goal of this is that you can select your rank first, then select the desire rank.
After choosing this, the price is displayed. Im trying to do this function.
For example, you select the lowest rank possible, then your landing (1-2-3).
Then, you choose what is the rank that you want, so in total, there is 4 divs clicked.
Finally, the goal of it all is to show the price.
But im having troubles. If you guys have some ideas.

I know that this is not the good way to do it. The code below is an example (Silver 1 to Silver 2).

I'm sure that I can condense this but I don't know how (Because there is a lot of ranks and doing 50 functions is not a good idea I think).
I hope to have been clear and precise, thanks for your help.

```js
//First part
var fer1 = 0;
var bronze1 = 0;
var argent1 = 0;
var or1 = 0;
var platine1 = 0;
var diamant1 = 0;
var immortel1 = 0;
var un1 = 0;
var deux1 = 0;
var trois1 = 0;

//Second part
var fer2 = 0;
var bronze2 = 0;
var argent2 = 0;
var or2 = 0;
var platine2 = 0;
var diamant2 = 0;
var immortel2 = 0;
var un2 = 0;
var deux2 = 0;
var trois2 = 0;

function P1() {
  fer1 = 1;
  bronze1 = 0;
  argent1 = 0;
  or1 = 0;
  platine1 = 0;
  diamant1 = 0;
  immortel1 = 0;


  if ((fer1 == 1 && fer2 == 1 && un1 == 1 && deux2 == 1)) {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "100€"
  } else {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "0€"
  }
}

function P8() {
  un1 = 1;
  deux1 = 0;
  trois1 = 0;
  if ((fer1 == 1 && fer2 == 1 && un1 == 1 && deux2 == 1)) {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "100€"
  } else {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "0€"
  }
}

function P11() {
  fer2 = 1;
  bronze2 = 0;
  argent2 = 0;
  or2 = 0;
  platine2 = 0;
  diamant2 = 0;
  immortel2 = 0;
  if ((fer1 == 1 && fer2 == 1 && un1 == 1 && deux2 == 1)) {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "100€"
  } else {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "0€"
  }
}

function P99() {
  un2 = 0;
  deux2 = 1;
  trois2 = 0;
  if ((fer1 == 1 && fer2 == 1 && un1 == 1 && deux2 == 1)) {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "100€"
  } else {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "0€"
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="selection2">
                <h1 class="unselectable policeOA policeRS" style="background-color:black; color:white;"> VOTRE RANG SOUHAITÉ</h1>
                <div class="SousSelection1">
                    <div class="contenu-grille">
                        <div class="foc">
                            <div class="PetitCarre customClass" id="pc11">  
                            <img class="rankss unselectable" src="http://localhost:8080/fullvaloAZ\FullValoCreated\HTML\esports\build\assets\images\Rank\Silver.png"/>
                            <img  id="s1" class="unselectable slash1" src="http://localhost:8080/fullvaloAZ\FullValoCreated\HTML\esports\build\assets\images\All\Slashwhite.png"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="foc">
                            <div class="PetitCarre" id="pc22">
                            <img class="rankss unselectable" src="http://localhost:8080/fullvaloAZ\FullValoCreated\HTML\esports\build\assets\images\Rank\Bronze.png"/>
                            <img id="s2" class="unselectable slash2" src="http://localhost:8080/fullvaloAZ\FullValoCreated\HTML\esports\build\assets\images\All\Slashwhite.png"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="foc">
                            <div class="PetitCarre" id="pc33">
                            <img class="rankss unselectable" src="http://localhost:8080/fullvaloAZ\FullValoCreated\HTML\esports\build\assets\images\Rank\Argent.png"/>
                            <img id="s3" class="unselectable slash3" src="http://localhost:8080/fullvaloAZ\FullValoCreated\HTML\esports\build\assets\images\All\Slashwhite.png"/>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Whenever you have variables like `xx1`, `xx2`, etc. they can usually be replaced with an array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give the divs the same class name the select them using querySelectorAll then create forEach loop on them add click event listener for them inside the event check for the current rank and div rank then return the required price also insted of using fer1 fer2 use [fer1,fer2] it would be much better. if you could provide the html maybe I could help more

**UPDATE**
you can modify this as it fit your project

```
// ranks variable will hold all the ranks
// currentRank will hold the user current rank if user have current rank
const ranks = document.querySelectorAll(".foc");
const currentRank = document.getElementById("");
const total = document.getElementById("total");
let upgradePrice = 0;
// this will loop over every rank div you have
ranks.forEach(rank=>{
    // then we will add event listener for mouse clicks
    rank.addEventListener("click",event=>{
        // here you will write the upgrade logic like checking the clicked div id 
        // so you can know which rank is this and if you need to do any
        // validation you can do it here then after you finish you can
        // add the upgrade cost to upgradePrice variable so you show it to user
        // and be able to use it in another part in your code if needed
        // also if you want to get id or class of any element in the rank div 
        // or the parent element of the div you can use `event`
        // you can search for the propertys you can use with `event.target` in google
        // you can get the id of the div or the id of any element inside it use event argument
        // const rankId = event.target.id <- this the div id
        upgradePrice+=100
        // after you finish you can change the div style to using `event.target.style`
        // event.target.style.background = "red"; <- to mark the div as selected
        total.innerHTML = `${upgradePrice}€`
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your return bro ! Im better understanding now, but im a bit lost about how should I start. Of course I can show you the HTML but even this part is big. How can I show you ?

Comment: @Zartex I don't need to see the whole part but the first 3 or 5 divs cuz all the other divs are the same

Comment: Sure, should i post it on my original post ? or Here.

Comment: @Zartex original post

Comment: I did it on the original post, take a look

Comment: @Zartex OK can you answer some questions for me first is selection2 class is selection div or it is the div that holds other selections like a container, second what is foc class for and PetitCarre for –

Comment: Hello ! Im sorry I had corona, so I wasn't really active :( 
Selection2 is the whole container about this part. Each rank has 'foc' & 'PetitCarre'.
By the way, I showed you the second part of the HTML, I mean, there is the same below with 'selection1'. And I only showed you the half of the HTML for "selection2". Im a bit confuse about where should I start with your code right now, let me know if you have any questions. Thanks !

Comment: @Zartex I hope you feel alright now take good care of yourself, about the answer I have updated it give it a look

Comment: Hey man, im doing better now, I took a long time to answer im sorry, thanks a lot for your time ! Im currently looking on your code, and to be more precise : there is inevitably  a starting rank. So they have to choose their first rank, then the desire one. But the thing is : how do I do that because depending on the rank they choose the price has to varies. Do you know I can do that ? Thanks man

Comment: I was wondering, if you have some minutes to help me, we can maybe talk on Discord or anything ? Because I have some pictures which can help to understand, and it's hard on this to show you everything, my Discord is Zartex#8635 if ever, otherwise I would understand that you don't want no problem

Comment: hi, @Zartex I am so sorry I didn't reply to your comment sooner the past few days had been rough on me I didn't open StackOverflow if you didn't solve it already I have sent a request on discord